# Chrome Performance tab reporting hundreds of function calls that didn't happen

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm troubleshooting a performance issue with my webapp. I have a reproduceable bug that causes frame times of 6-9 seconds. This is obviously not ideal performance, so I'm using the Performance tab of the Chrome DevTools to look into it.

[image: Performance chart]

During the long frame, it appears that my function (the highest purple row) is called hundreds of times, each call lasting for 0.7ms to 5ms. (Hovering the mouse over them reveals that each one has a different time associated) Then, over to the right there's one much longer call (515ms) which to me seems more realistic (the function does a lot of complex stuff and I'm haven't optimised it yet).

I put a console.log() statement as the first line in my function and it only gets called once. If my function is only called once why does it appear so many times in the Performance chart? Am I reading this wrongly?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: It's a bug. The samples should be merged internally. Consider submitting a report on https://crbug.com if the bug isn't fixed in Chrome Canary, which is installed separately.

Comment: Same thing in Canary, I'll report it.

Comment: Here's the bug, I didn't create it but I found it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=768540

Comment: Also see the related issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798232